# Excel Workbook must be reopened to see updates from DataFrame / StyleFrame

Tags: python-3.x, excel, dataframe, styleframe

I am writing a StyleFrame to a new Excel sheet, but I cannot see the changes until I reopen the Workbook. How can I see the update immediately? I tried using a DataFrame as well but with the same result.

```
writer = StyleFrame.ExcelWriter(cls.wb_path)
writer.book = cls.wb
sf.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Extra fields", header=False, index=False)
writer.save()
```

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [`pandas` docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html), you need to provide `mode='a'` when creating the `ExcelWrite` object.

At the moment this is not possible through the `StyleFrame.ExcelWriter` shortcut, but you can use `pandas.ExcelWriter`:

```
import pandas as pd

from styleframe import StyleFrame, Styler

sf = StyleFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3]}, styler_obj=Styler(bg_color='yellow'))
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx', mode='a')
sf.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Extra fields")
writer.save()
```

`test.xlsx` before running the above code:

[image]

`test.xlsx` after running the above code:

[image]

[image]

Regarding

> I cannot see the changes until I reopen the Workbook

This has nothing to do with `pandas`, `styleframe`, `openpyxl` or even Python in general. You only see the change when you reopen Excel (or any other spreadsheet software you are using) because that is how the said software (or even the OS you are using) is designed. Actually, I'm surprised you even managed to execute the code while the file was open. Usually, you get an explicit PermissionError error if you try to save a sheet to a file which is currently opened:

```
writer.save()
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'test.xlsx'
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! I already managed writing to an open Excel file in MacOS (even without `mode=a`), but I assumed I could also use this code for Windows. How can I write to an open Excel file in Windows? Or do I need something else then StyleFrame for that?

Comment: @Rezzy777 You can't. Windows will not allow that.

Comment: Got it, I'll have to look for an other solution (without Python) then. Many thanks again!